# Fancybox onClose not working

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I am trying to redirect to the URL that is on my "onclose" attribute of the .fancybox ... it just does work. Any ideas? Code is below. Note: the modal appears fine, but when the user presses the "x" at the top... the screen is just blank.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 showModal();


          function showModal() {


            var url = document.URL;
            var popUp = '//local.meau.com/Support-Center/Service-Notifications/Search-Tips.aspx';
            var site = popUp;


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.fancybox({
                    'width': 500,
                    'height': '55%',
                    'autoScale': false,
                    'transitionIn': 'none',
                    'transitionOut': 'none',
                    'type': 'iframe',
                    'href': site,
                    'showCloseButton': true,
                    'onClose' : function(){location.href = "http://local.meau.com/Support-Center.aspx";}

                });

            });



        }


    </script>
```

Comment: maybe because the right name of the callback is **`onClosed`** (fancybox v1.3.4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

updated your code to read

```
window.location = "http://local.meau.com/Support-Center.aspx"
```

Double check your onClose callback as well

- v1.2 - http://fancybox.net/api/126 - `callbackOnClose`
- v1.3 - http://fancybox.net/api - `onClosed`
- v2.0 - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs - `beforeClose` or
  `afterClose`

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel what version of Fancybox are you using? I don't think your onClose callback is correct.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel and the solution was?

Comment: I don't remember, haven't used that in about a year. that was two client's ago